# Is it not advisable to have a visible cancel option when performing a action such as delete

Tags: call-to-action, cancel

I was reading about the guidelines for flyouts for Metro Design which state that:

> Include just the action that the user initiated, such as Delete. Do
>   not include the opposite action or a Cancel button; that can be
>   achieved by dismissing the Flyout.

[image]

I do understand that there is an option to prevent the delete from taking place by clicking outside the flyout but assuming I was using the metro layout for the first time,i would get confused about what to prevent this from happening since i see no apparent cancel button.

So my question is: *When performing actions like delete or say format which might be not be non reversible, wouldnt it be advisable to have a cancel button instead of relying on the belief that the user might know the alternate way to cancel the action (which happens to be hidden)*

Comment: Could you link to the flyout guidelines you're reading? I'd like to read them before responding.

Answer (score 2):

I do not like that guideline. Trying to be innovative with important user actions can be dangerous. I don't think there is any doubt that users are familliar with the "ok" and "cancel" options in such confirmation boxes.

A flyout with just one option (ie. "Ok") used to be containing information like ie. "You can't do that here." that doesn't activate an action.

People I know still have problems with closing a light box shown picture without a clear close action so what would happen with important decisions?

Answer (score 0):

I also don't think that would be the best route to go down. For some users they may become under the belief that the *only* option is to delete the images and that they have no choice. Instead I would go for the traditional route of "Delete/Don't delete".

If you decide to use buttons also be careful about the wording as this could also be confusing to some users. For example, I found this article on the usage of the "Cancel" button: http://uxmovement.com/forms/killing-the-cancel-button-on-forms-for-good/

Comment: That article specifically talks about Cancel buttons on forms, and in fact the article encourages Cancel buttons on confirmation dialogues like the one in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Jakob Nielsen's 10 Usability Heuristics for User Interface Design has two points I want to focus on that shows that not having a cancel - or emergency exit - button is a bad idea for usability.

> **User control and freedom**
>   Users often choose system functions by mistake and will need a clearly marked "emergency exit" to leave the unwanted state without having to go through an extended dialogue. Support undo and redo.
>
> **Error prevention**
>   Even better than good error messages is a careful design which prevents a problem from occurring in the first place. Either eliminate error-prone conditions or check for them and present users with a confirmation option before they commit to the action.
>
> from [Jakob Nielsen's 10 Usability Heuristics](http://www.useit.com/papers/heuristic/heuristic_list.html)

The alternative is to rely on an undo feature, but the fact that a user can delete (and will) information by mistake should be prevented in the first place.

The Usability Body of Knowledge lists these three principles of usable design under error prevention:

> **Error Prevention and Handling:**
>
> **Forgiveness:** Allow reasonable variations in input. Prevent the user from making serious errors whenever possible, and ask for user confirmation before allowing a potentially destructive action.
>
> **Error recovery:** Provide clear, plain-language messages to describe the problem and suggest a solution to help users recover from any errors.
>
> **Undo and redo:** Provide "emergency exits" to allow users to abandon an unwanted action. The ability to reverse actions relieves anxiety and encourages user exploration of unfamiliar options.
>
> from [Usability Body of Knowledge: Principals of Usable Design](http://www.usabilitybok.org/principles-for-usable-design)

So clearly there are substantial reasons to not remove the emergency exit paths as user will make mistakes.